# Sliding box error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[This](http://danithemes.fanscity.eu/shugar) is my webpage. As you can see, when you hover the 'ads' button, the transition only shows a part of the advertisement. I want it to show the entire AD. Here's the code I'm using

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {$(".wcfbslide").hover(function() {$(this).stop().animate({right: "-5"}, "slow");}, function() {$(this).stop().animate({right: "-300"}, "medium");}, 500);});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .wcfbslide{
         background: url("http://danithemes.fanscity.eu/shugar/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/ads1.png") no-repeat scroll left center transparent !important;
         display: block; 
         float: right;
         height: 110px;
         padding:0 5px 0 46px;
         width: 295px;
         z-index: 99999;
         position:fixed;
         right:-300px;
         top:30%;
    }

    .wcfbslide div {
        border:none;
        position:relative;
        display:block;
    }

    .wc-gplusfollow {
         position: relative;
         padding: 10px;    
         background:#ffffff;     
         border: 1px solid #ccc;
         box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
</style>
    <div class="wcfbslide">
        <div class="wc-gplusfollow">
            <script src="http://fanscity.eu/ads/728x90.js"></script>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just increase the value of the "right" attribute, now on hover it goes right: -5px, try making it right 440px.

```
$(this).stop().animate({right: "440px"}, "slow");
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! But the white background is more small than the AD.

Comment: @PLLOnAbc Just give the wc-gplusfollow class element the same width as the container 
    .wc-gplusfollow {
        width: 728px;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the banner is 728 pixels long, therefore ".wcfbslide" should have a width of at least 728px (width: 728px;). It's initially hidden : set the right attribute to -728px (right: -728px;).

Then, you need to change your animation to :

```
$(document).ready(function() {$(".wcfbslide").hover(function() {$(this).stop().animate({right: "0"}, "slow");}, function() {$(this).stop().animate({right: "-728"}, "medium");}, 500);});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your width's and margins need a little bit of adjusting. JSFiddle won't display the image though.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/en2zu1w4/)

Javascript:

```
$(".wcfbslide").hover(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        right: "-5"
    }, "slow");
}, function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        right: "-735"
    }, "medium");
}, 500);
```

CSS:

```
.wcfbslide {
    background: url("http://danithemes.fanscity.eu/shugar/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/ads1.png") no-repeat scroll left center transparent !important;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    height: 110px;
    padding:0 5px 0 46px;
    width: 728px;
    z-index: 99999;
    position:fixed;
    right:-735px;
    top:30%;
}
```